# PDFtron lastest versoin imported base 64 images are low quality

Tags: javascript, pdf, vuejs2, sign, pdftron

I have a project in laravel 8 with vue 2, i made an implementation of pdftron where i save the signatures user creates into a database as base64 images, so far all good, problem comes when i load those images from the database, although i can see them in the signature tool they are extremely low quality and i can no longer change color to the image, which doesn't happen in the demo sites, i think that when they get exported they become something that pdftron can no longer manipulate as a newly created signature, so i would like to know if someone else has this problem and a possible solution for it, i'll put the code i'm using and the images for you here

Above saved siganture, down new signature

[image: 1]

```
let that = this;

    const viewerElement = document.getElementById('webviewer');

    WebViewer({
        path: '/js/WebViewer/lib',
        initialDoc: this.initialDoc,
        extension: 'pdf',
    }, viewerElement)
        .then((instance) => {

            const { documentViewer, annotationManager } = instance.Core;

            const signatureTool = documentViewer.getTool('AnnotationCreateSignature');

            documentViewer.addEventListener('documentLoaded', () => {

                instance.UI.setLanguage(that.locale);

                let signatures = JSON.parse(that.savedSignatures);

                signatures = signatures.map(a => a.base64_signature);

                signatureTool.importSignatures(["data:image/png;base64, " + signatures]); //base64 images array

                document.getElementById('app').setAttribute('style', 'padding: 0');
                document.getElementById('loader-container').classList.add('d-none');
                document.getElementById('all-pages-content').removeAttribute('style')
                document.getElementById('downloadButton').setAttribute('style', 'visibility: visible')
                document.getElementById('pdf-ui').setAttribute('style', 'visibility: visible')

            });

            documentViewer.addEventListener('annotationsLoaded', async () => {
                annotationManager.addEventListener('annotationDrawn', async (annotationList) => {
                    console.log('1')
                    annotationList.forEach(annotation => {
                        if (annotation.Subject === "Signature")
                            that.extractAnnotationSignature(annotation, documentViewer);
                    })
                })
            });

            let saveSignedPdf = document.getElementById('downloadButton');

            saveSignedPdf.addEventListener('click', async () => {

                const doc = documentViewer.getDocument();
                const xfdfString = await annotationManager.exportAnnotations();
                const data = await doc.getFileData({
                    // saves the document with annotations in it
                    xfdfString
                });
                const arr = new Uint8Array(data);
                const blob = new Blob([arr], {type: 'application/pdf'});

                await that.processDocument(blob)
                // Add code for handling Blob here
            })

            // instance.disableElements(['downloadButton', 'printButton']);
            // instance.disableElements(['toolbarGroup-Insert']);

            return instance
        });
```

and here is the code i use to export the images taken from official docs

async extractAnnotationSignature(annotation, docViewer) {

```
        let that = this;
        // Create a new Canvas to draw the Annotation on
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        // Reference the annotation from the Document
        const pageMatrix = docViewer.getDocument().getPageMatrix(annotation.PageNumber);
        // Set the height & width of the canvas to match the annotation
        canvas.height = annotation.Height;
        canvas.width = annotation.Width;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        // Translate the Annotation to the top Top Left Corner of the Canvas ie (0, 0)
        ctx.translate(-annotation.X, -annotation.Y);
        // Draw the Annotation onto the Canvas
        annotation.draw(ctx, pageMatrix);
        // Convert the Canvas to a Blob Object for Upload
        canvas.toBlob((blob) => {

            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('signature', blob);
            formData.append('customer_id', that.customerId);

            const config = {
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content,
                }
            }

            axios.post(that.saveSignatureUrl, formData, config)
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (!response.data.success) {
                        console.log("could not save signature for future use")
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("saved signature for future use")
                    }
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    that.output = error;
                    console.log("could not reach backend")
                });
        });
    }
```

I know you will see several flaws in this code, I'm a rookie so please bear with me, thank you for your time, and any help is appreciated

test base64 string generated with this code

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

i also tried exportSIgnatures and i got the same base64 string for already saved signature that look blurry but for new ones i got this, which i don't quite understand what it is and how to use it for reconstructing the images

[[[{"x":181.15942028985506,"y":1.4492753623188406},{"x":178.2608695652174,"y":1.4492753623188406},{"x":168.1159420289855,"y":7.246376811594203},{"x":150.7246376811594,"y":23.18840579710145},{"x":128.9855072463768,"y":40.57971014492754},{"x":85.5072463768116,"y":66.66666666666667},{"x":56.52173913043478,"y":82.6086956521739},{"x":17.391304347826086,"y":98.55072463768116},{"x":2.898550724637681,"y":104.34782608695652},{"x":1.4492753623188406,"y":104.34782608695652},{"x":1.4492753623188406,"y":102.89855072463769},{"x":4.3478260869565215,"y":89.85507246376811},{"x":17.391304347826086,"y":65.21739130434783},{"x":24.63768115942029,"y":57.971014492753625},{"x":44.927536231884055,"y":43.47826086956522},{"x":50.72463768115942,"y":43.47826086956522},{"x":59.42028985507246,"y":43.47826086956522},{"x":73.91304347826087,"y":50.72463768115942},{"x":79.71014492753623,"y":57.971014492753625},{"x":95.65217391304348,"y":73.91304347826087},{"x":123.18840579710145,"y":97.10144927536231},{"x":149.2753623188406,"y":115.94202898550725},{"x":176.81159420289856,"y":128.9855072463768},{"x":182.6086956521739,"y":130.43478260869566},{"x":194.20289855072463,"y":130.43478260869566},{"x":198.55072463768116,"y":130.43478260869566}]]]

Comment: The signature control can list Drawn signatures (which are path data) and Text signatures (which are text rendered to bitmap). When you call exportSignatures, the returned array of items contains the Drawn signatures or images. In the snippets you put above, you've provided an image and a Drawn item. You can supply importSignatures with the object returned by exportSignatures and it will repopulate the signature control.

Answer (score 0):

Hello David Gabriel Lopez Duarte,

We were able to reproduce this issue, it is likely due to our canvas isnt being adjusted to match the zoom level. This has been reported before and is in our backlog!